# Getting 500 error with because ajax can't access my php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to develop the front end of a simple login test webpage. Basically I the website should be able to just display to the user if the login was or was not successful. The message should be text right below the login form. The page should not have to be restarted, hence the ajax. I have to make the markup for the page, use ajax to send the data to my PHP file, where I curl my information to the middle end. The middle end will then send me a response and I am to parse that into a string and just display the string to the user. The middle end will return something like: `{"message":"login failed","success":false}`. And I would just need to put a message right below the log in form saying `login failed`. My three files are included below:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Login Alpha</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Log In</h1>
    <br>
    <form name="alphalogin" method="post" action="front-connect.php" id="input_form">
      <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="User..."><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password..."><br>
      <input type="button" value="Log In" id="login">
    </form>
    <div id="responce"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

scripts.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login").on('click', function () {
    var user = $("#user").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    if (user == "" || password == "")
        alert('Please check inputs');
    else {
    $.ajax(
        {
        url: 'front-connect.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            user: user,
            password: password
        },

        success: function (responce) {
            $("#responce").html(responce);
        },
        dataType: 'text'
        });
    }
    });
});
```

front-connect.php

```
<?php
$parmas = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$user = $parmas->{'user'};
$password = $parmas->{'password'};

$post = array("user" => $user, "pass" => $password);
$transfer = json_encode($post);

$ctrl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ctrl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://web.njit.edu/~bgb7/login/login.php");
curl_setopt($ctrl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ctrl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $transfer);
curl_setopt($ctrl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ctrl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$responce = curl_exec($ctrl);
$responce = json_decode($responce, 0);
curl_close($ctrl);

exit($responce);

?>
```

If you want to see it on a webserver now the website is being hosted here: https://web.njit.edu/~cfr5/cs490/

Thanks!

Comment: There's something wrong with your `PHP` code.

Comment: `$parmas = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` will not work, your are sending form data not json data. Just use `$_POST['user']`

Answer (score 0):

Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in the last line 'exit($responce);'

Comment: Maybe you have no need to `$responce = json_decode($responce, 0);` If you want to response with JSON.